# deploying error with heroku desc="No web processes running"

Tags: node.js, heroku

i am deploying my app to heroku it is written in Node.js  the main script is main.js looks like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync('count.json');
var Words = JSON.parse(file);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('we are listeining'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({ limit : '1mb' })); 


app.get('/add/:word', addWord);

function addWord(request, response) {
  var data = request.params;
  var word = data.word;
  var reply;
  var found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < Words.length; i++){
    if (Words[i].type == word){
      Words[i].count++;
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

if (!found) {
  Words.push({"type": word , "count": 1});
}

  var x = JSON.stringify(Words, null, 2);
  fs.writeFile('count.json', x, finished);

  function finished(){
    console.log('Yay')
  }
    /* 
    console.log(Words[word]); */

/*     response.send(reply); */
  }
```

i am also have deployed the Procfile to be

```
worker: node main.js
```

but still having this problem and this is the logs of heroku

```
2020-05-09T22:56:21.244885+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-09T22:56:24.487998+00:00 app[worker.1]: we are listeining
2020-05-09T22:56:34.768703+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=bss-ticketmaker.herokuapp.com request_id=7e7b9f8d-6ffb-4d93-9691-c9024f1a576a fwd="156.205.74.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-09T22:56:36.265759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bss-ticketmaker.herokuapp.com request_id=8d817eeb-c233-44b0-ba76-be54907533a6 fwd="156.205.74.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a web server so in the `Procfile` set `web` instead of `worker`.

```
web: node main.js
```

Heroku will route HTTP requests to processes started with the `web` name.

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly fine , i am very grateful for your assist